# Accessing Table data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def getDates(URL):
    dates = []
    # if page not found, HTTPError is thrown
    try:
        html = urlopen(URL)
    except HTTPError:
        print("Page not found.")
        return None

    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    data = bsObj.find("table", {"class":"sortable wikitable"}).children
    for child in data:
        print(child)
```

Yields the following sample output:

```
<tr>
<td><a href="/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards" title="89th Academy Awards">89th</a></td>
<td>February 26, 2017</td>
<td>2016</td>
<td><i><a href="/wiki/Moonlight_(2016_film)" title="Moonlight (2016 film)">Moonlight</a></i></td>
<td><span class="sortkey" style="display:none;">217 !</span><span class="sorttext">3 hours, 49 minutes</span></td>
<td>32.9 million</td>
<td>22.4</td>
<td rowspan="2"><a href="/wiki/Jimmy_Kimmel" title="Jimmy Kimmel">Jimmy Kimmel</a></td>
</tr>
```

The only row I want to scrape is the row with the date. Here, it is **February 26, 2017**. There are about 80+ entries just like this.  I have tried asking for the sibling of the top `td` row and got a `NavigableString error`, which I could not except or loop my way out of (as suggested in other posts), as Spyder said NavigableString was undefined, could not be imported, and was not a recognised error (excepting it as an `AttributeError` yielded a blank screen). I get that there is a blank space there. I've tried finding every child with a `td` tag that has a string that resolves to a regular expression corresponding to a date. That didn't work either. The error said I could put that parameter in my .find() function, though the docs -- which I have in front of me -- say otherwise.

Thoughts on what is going wrong, and how I might get this one row?

Comment: If the placement of the date in the table is same, then why don't you take an array of all the td's in the table and select the td you want with the index

Comment: @bigbounty -- Thanks for the reply! There's some intuitive appeal to that. This being my first attempt at using BS4, I can't help but wonder why I can't simply loop through each child and say, "Give me the second "td" tag." This shouldn't be a big deal, should it? Or am I oversimplifying?

Comment: Or extract the table contents and put it into a variable say "table". From this variable again select all the tds with find_all and select the td which you want using indexes

Comment: In order to access list elements you don't need to loop through the list, just index is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle all the `<td>` tags like a list, then you can call the *index* on the list to get the *second* item:

```
html_doc = """
    <tr>
    <td><a href="/wiki/89th_Academy_Awards" title="89th Academy Awards">89th</a></td>
    <td>February 26, 2017</td>
    <td>2016</td>
    <td><i><a href="/wiki/Moonlight_(2016_film)" title="Moonlight (2016 film)">Moonlight</a></i></td>
    <td><span class="sortkey" style="display:none;">217 !</span><span class="sorttext">3 hours, 49 minutes</span></td>
    <td>32.9 million</td>
    <td>22.4</td>
    <td rowspan="2"><a href="/wiki/Jimmy_Kimmel" title="Jimmy Kimmel">Jimmy Kimmel</a></td>
    </tr>
    """

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

all_tds = soup.find_all('td')

print all_tds[1].text # index the 2nd item
```

output:

```
February 26, 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex is probably the right way to go, Index could be wrong**

The date cell could be in any column, do not assume it is the second column (do you also generate the html? Does your generation enable a variable to control both generation and processing? Is there a fetch layer in between?). There could be simple changes in the future (such as ordering or configurable table columns) that could break your change. Consider the following code.

```
re_months = '(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)'
re_int = '[0-9]+'
date_row_matcher = re.compile('<td>{months} {days}, {years}</td>'.format(months=re_months, days=re_int, years=re_int))

rows = bsObj.find("table", {"class":"sortable wikitable"}).children
for row in rows:
    for cell in row.children:
        match = re.match(date_row_matcher, str(cell))
        if match is not None:
            print cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys, for the clarifications concerning the need for loops, the use of tags, and the usefulness of regex. The following code produced the desired result.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def getDates(URL):
    # if page not found, HTTPError is thrown
    try:
        html = urlopen(URL)
    except HTTPError:
        print("Page not found.")
        return None

    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    data = bsObj.find("table", {"class":"sortable wikitable"})
    table_data = data.find_all("td", string=re.compile("^[A-Za-z]+\ [0-9]+,\ [0-9]+"))
    print(table_data)

getDates("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Academy_Awards_ceremonies")
```

The set of results looks like this:

> [May 16, 1929, April 3, 1930, November 5, 1930, November 10, 1931, November 18, 1932, March 16, 1934, February 27, 1935, March 5, 1936, March 4, 1937, March 10, 1938, February 23, 1939, February 29, 1940, February 27, 1941, February 26, 1942, March 4, 1943, March 2, 1944, March 15, 1945, March 7, 1946, March 13, 1947, March 20, 1948, March 24, 1949, March 23, 1950, March 29, 1951, March 20, 1952, March 19, 1953, March 25, 1954, March 30, 1955, March 21, 1956, March 27, 1957, March 26, 1958, April 6, 1959, April 4, 1960, April 17, 1961, April 9, 1962, April 8, 1963, April 13, 1964, April 5, 1965, April 18, 1966, April 10, 1967, April 10, 1968, April 14, 1969, April 7, 1970, April 15, 1971, April 10, 1972, March 27, 1973, April 2, 1974, April 8, 1975, March 29, 1976, March 28, 1977, April 3, 1978, April 9, 1979, April 14, 1980, March 31, 1981, March 29, 1982, April 11, 1983, April 9, 1984, March 25, 1985, March 24, 1986, March 30, 1987, April 11, 1988, March 29, 1989, March 26, 1990, March 25, 1991, March 30, 1992, March 29, 1993, March 21, 1994, March 27, 1995, March 25, 1996, March 24, 1997, March 23, 1998, March 21, 1999, March 26, 2000, March 25, 2001, March 24, 2002, March 23, 2003, February 29, 2004, February 27, 2005, March 5, 2006, February 25, 2007, February 24, 2008, February 22, 2009, March 7, 2010, February 27, 2011, February 26, 2012, February 24, 2013, March 2, 2014, February 22, 2015, February 28, 2016, February 26, 2017]